# Can SVM method deal with 1 dimensional data for forecasting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, svm

I am working on using SVM to predict the future values of one particular 1D data. The data contains 54 month sales values and with their month indexes from 1 to 54. The first problem is that I think the SVM could do the prediction but I am not quit sure about it. As I know, SVM could do the classification but how about the regression? Could anyone tell me about why SVM can do the regression?

And in my problem, I tried to set the X as month indexes and y as the value for each month. I am not quite sure if I was doing right as there is no label(or the label I've tired using the value) and feature is only the month index.

I tried to fit it by `from sklearn import svm` and get the result that the accuracy for training  set is 100% and 0 for testing set. I do not know where is wrong.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('11.csv', header=None, names = ['a', 'b', 'c'])

X = df['b'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['c'].values.reshape(-1,1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

from sklearn import svm

clf = svm.SVC(C=0.8, kernel='rbf', gamma=20, decision_function_shape='ovr')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

print("training result：",clf.score(X_train, y_train))

print("testing result：",clf.score(X_test,y_test))
```

The dataset looks like this X = [1, 2, 3, 4,...,53, 54] and y = [90, 18, 65, 150.... 289], 1D dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVM for regression purposes is called **Support Vector Regression (SVR)** and it's available in the *sklearn* module.

Instead of `svm.SVC()` you need to use `svm.SVR()` with the appropriate parameters. And yes, 1D data should be fine.

[Here is a more complete example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html).

Comment: 1d means one column. If you have only one column lets say one feature (X), then on what basis you are training your data without having the second column (Y). Even you are predicting the same column against a timestamp, wouldn't timestamp be considered as a column as well?

Comment: @MUK The code in the question contains the example for a 1D problem: `X` contains the feature and `y` the ground truth. Of course, having only 1 feature is a terrible thing for predicting or classifying things accurately but programming-wise, it is fine to pass a 1D vector to SVR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use regression algorithms for forecasting. The general approach of how to adapt regression algorithms to forecasting problems is described [here](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/41231210/Machine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser20160114-28513-1pqgoe9.pdf20160115-19908-phg1xc.pdf?1452888125=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DMachine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser.pdf&Expires=1591446976&Signature=KbtlBoQ9O~TROgo8AuK94U2O-BbERykqDk4HCGV0HNPnXECBPlSv500cQ49dZ-qsYH1u2iq6JS6a-oh4yO2T45kfGJqckKp7P-M~OcbhlpqRA3CtD832SGTcavThNR58mfmF25eN7x5qN137eyBJGrfNmtC0f-ZVRIs~ZRafSrYMKeykvXc7m12DKKuprq~dslLaDHV-OOvJb5f42aAH0PUb-MrN72Cka3Y1DO7hPUVCnD1XmpLNBc7I4-yrAO8GKKvd9-4i9V1NpauHfShnDD65zO2n8avUeMx86~izSvscSNRwW2qZXkZmXSUTvyOWrcJpSyvUmK2I3kTbQxBVcg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA).

Also make sure you properly evaluate your forecasting algorithms. When you use `train_test_split` you random shuffle and split your data. Instead you should only use past data to fit your algorithm and evaluate against future data.

If you're interested, we're developing a toolbox that extends scikit-learn for exactly these use cases. So with [sktime](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/sktime), you could simply write:

```
import numpy as np
from sktime.datasets import load_airline
from sktime.forecasting.compose import ReducedRegressionForecaster
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import temporal_train_test_split
from sktime.performance_metrics.forecasting import smape_loss

y = load_airline()  # load 1-dimensional time series
y_train, y_test = temporal_train_test_split(y)  
fh = np.arange(1, len(y_test) + 1)  # forecasting horizon
regressor = SVR()  
forecaster = ReducedRegressionForecaster(regressor, window_length=10)
forecaster.fit(y_train)
y_pred = forecaster.predict(fh)
print(smape_loss(y_test, y_pred))
>>> 0.139046791779424
```